# How to add name to a particular dimension of a data frame?

Tags: r, time-series

I have created 100 time series, and I found out the Dimension Year is currently not having a name, this has possibly caused some problems. How could I give a name to this column/dimension? Here are my code:

```
#create randome 1000 time series 
d <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
library(forecast)
lst1 <- lapply(d, ts, start = 2000, end = 2009)

# convert t to matrix or data frame which is now a list to use in dcc.fit
df <- do.call(cbind,lst1)
```

I checked then with `str(df)` and I found:

```
Time-Series [1:10, 1:100] from 2000 to 2009: 83 99 80 35 65 82 59 25 58 79 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:100] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
```

And we could also see from a part of this dataset, that the first column is not having a name:

```
      X95 X96 X97 X98 X99 X100
2000  35  92  91  12   8   34
2001  59  27  41  19   3   83
2002  38  89  74  53  33   23
2003  76  70  30  12  85   48
2004  28  41  95  17  73   55
2005  39  20  30  91  44   82
2006  59  50  95   5  82   96
2007  39  24  16  56  27    2
2008  20  33   7  88  43   16
2009  27  26  74  37  71   51
```

Could someone please help me adding a name to this year dimension? Thanks a lot! As you could see from the code, the data frame was generated from lists.

Comment: `[1:10, 1:100]` suggests it is a `matrix` not a `data.frame` (confirmed with `class(df)` returning something like `c("mts", "ts", "matrix")`). And that first "column" (with `2000` and `2001`, etc) are the row names. Some tools use them, some eschew them (such as `dplyr`). One cannot add a "column name" to the row names. If you want them as a column, then `df$names <- rownames(df)` or similar.

Comment: I thought like X95, X96 etc. are time series, from 2000 to 2009. What you meant is, actually 2000 is the row name of the first row? so actually it does not matter if there is no name for this row names? I fit a model on this matrix, but then I received an error: "error in dimnames(x) - dn length of 'dimnames' 2 not equal to array extent". I thought something is wrong with the dimension names as the error message describes.

Comment: That error might be due to something else, I'm not sure. Perhaps you should revamp this question into that (including the model-fitting code) or open a new question (which, when answered, may eventually make this question moot).

Comment: @r2evans yes I found out the error was caused by the spec of the GARCH-Model. Thanks for your help, now I won't confuse a row name with a column name anymore :)